# Why is completeness of reals a second-order sentence?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Can’t we state the completeness of reals in the following way?

> For every nonempty $X\in\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{R} )$, if $X$ is bounded above by some $a\in \mathbb{R}$, then $X$ has a unique least upper bound.

Note that the formulas “$X$ is bounded above” and “$X$ has a least upper bound” are expressible in first-order language.

Then why is this not a first-order sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terms "first-order" or "definable" or all these other stuff, are *extremely* unhelpful if you don't understand the context.

In this case, completeness is a second-order statement over the structure $(\Bbb R,<,+,\cdot,0,1)$. Indeed, you are literally quantifying over *all* $X\subseteq\Bbb R$. That is the exact meaning of a second-order statement.

But you might be confused, since this is a first-order statement from a set-theoretic point of view. And this is why set theory is a very nice foundation of mathematics: it takes these "naturally higher-order statements about natural objects" and convert them all into first-order statements about sets.

Comment: Yes, I was asking from the set theoretic point of view.

Comment: Just one more question Asaf: Suppose (informally) my theory (structure) does not contain $\in$ and nor any notion of sets. Then what would a second order statement look like?

Comment: Second-order has an implicit idea of sets. You can also think about it as $X$ being a predicate, and then writing $x\in X$ is the same as writing $X(x)$.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! One more thing please: Can I say that second-order theories are (at least?) two-sorted (that is they have two *types* of objects)? Or can they be one-sorted too (as your above predicate explanation suggests)?

Comment: Yes, this is how you get to type theory. You add higher and higher logic, as different types. You can think about this from the predicate perspective, though, yes. But since you quantify over these predicates, they are effectively a sort.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, Asaf!